# Android - Using email intent to send email without pressing "send"

Tags: android, email

Very similar to what is being asked here. [Sending email through intent without having to press send button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8677346/sending-email-through-intent-without-having-to-press-send-button)
But it wasn't really answered.

I wish to use this native application to send my email (without pressing the send button) as it gave me the feature of saving the mail to outbox whenever there is no internet connection and automatically help resume the sending whenever internet connection comes back.

I do not know how to do that using JavaMail. How do I handle such exception with JavaMail if I cannot use such intent?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the link, there is an answer for your question. 
And u want to add Diff jar 
    *

```
   - mail.jar
   * activation.jar
   * additionnal.jar
```

That Also desc in this link

[Send Email in Background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-android-ap/2033124#2033124)

Comment: Which link tells me about "saving the mail to outbox whenever there is no internet connection and automatically help resume the sending whenever internet connection comes back."?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-built-in-a)... it contains all the details of sending mail without `Intent` class or pressing send button of default GMail app of Android.